# Asymptotics (big-O) for power sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, euler-maclaurin

I am trying to prove the following equality, for $\alpha <-1$ and $x \geq 1$
$$\sum_{n \leq x}n^\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^\alpha+\mathcal{O}(x^{\alpha+1})$$
and have tried rearranging
$$\sum_{n \leq x}n^\alpha-\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^\alpha=\mathcal{O}(x^{\alpha+1})\implies \left|\sum_{n \geq x+1}n^\alpha\right| \leq cx^{\alpha+1}, \ c >0$$
I know that the series in the RHS converges by the $p$-series test. I am not sure I can use the Euler-Maclaurin formula since I would be required to use improper integrals to bound the sum. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You like to prove that for $x\geq 1$ and $\alpha<-1$
$$
\sum\limits_{n > x} {n^\alpha  }  = \mathcal{O}(x^{\alpha  + 1} ).
$$
We can bound the sum via an integral as follows. If $\left[ x \right]$ denotes the integer part of $x$ then
$$
\sum\limits_{n > x} {n^\alpha  }  \le \left[ x \right]^\alpha   + \sum\limits_{n \ge \left[ x \right] + 1} {n^\alpha  }  \le \left[ x \right]^\alpha   + \sum\limits_{n \ge \left[ x \right] + 1} {\int_{n - 1}^n {t^\alpha  dt} }  = \left[ x \right]^\alpha   + \int_{\left[ x \right]}^{ + \infty } {t^\alpha  dt} \\ = \left[ x \right]^\alpha   - \frac{{ \left[ x \right]^{\alpha  + 1} }}{{\alpha  + 1}} = \mathcal{O}(\left[ x \right]^\alpha  ) + \mathcal{O}(\left[ x \right]^{\alpha  + 1} ) = \mathcal{O}(x^\alpha  ) + \mathcal{O}(x^{\alpha  + 1} ) = \mathcal{O}(x^{\alpha  + 1} ).
$$

Comment: what happened to the integer part after the integral step? Thank you again!

Comment: @SimonTherien Thanks, corrected.

Comment: and wouldn't the last inequality be other way since powers are negative (for example $2^{-2} \geq 2.5^{-2}$)?